# PHP post request with file_get_content

Tags: php, post, token, file-get-contents

Please someone to help me

I'm trying to `POST` a request with `file_get_contents` and I receive a 415 code error message. I'm not a pro dev and I want to know what is wrong in my source code. Here is my problem:

1. I generate a token which is a parameter of the second request
2. the generated token must be used for the POST request

I receive a 415 Error code message. I don't know how to correct that source

```
$tok=file_get_contents('https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/gettoken/username/xxxx/password/xxxx');
$toke =json_decode($tok, true);
$token=$toke['token'];

$data = json_encode(
    array(
        'from' => 'TEST',
        'to' => '335546821546',
        'type'=> 'Text',
        'content'=> 'Test',
        'sendDateTime'=> '2020/07/07'
        )
);

$options = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Authorization Token " . base64_encode("$token"),
        'content' => $data
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$url = 'https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/send';

$result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
```

Comment: 415 Unsupported Media Type (RFC 7231)

Comment: are you getting $token?

Comment: Content-length, Content-type both request header is missing

Comment: Yes @VishalSolanki I get $token, but I dont know if I'm using it correctly. how must I change content-type and content-length?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting token and facing issue in post call only then i have noticed that you have missed a few Request Headers:

like Content-type, Content-length, I have check with the different URLs, It is working for me try it

```
<?php
    $tok=file_get_contents('https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/gettoken/username/xxxx/password/xxxx');
    $toke =json_decode($tok, true);
    $token=$toke['token'];

    $data = json_encode(
        array(
            'from' => 'TEST',
            'to' => '335546821546',
            'type'=> 'Text',
            'content'=> 'Test',
            'sendDateTime'=> '2020/07/07'
            )
    );

    $options = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
                        "Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n" .
                        "Authorization Token: " . base64_encode("$token") . "\r\n",
            'content' => $data
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $url = 'https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/send';

    $result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Hi  @VishalSolanki  here is the result: `failed to open stream:   Warning: file_get_contents(https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/send): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /htdocs/vishal.php on line 30  bool(false)`             Here is line 30:  `$result = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);`

Comment: Hi @vishalSolanki I'm confused here is the dev page of the API https://bulksmsonline.com/developers/        Restful API section.  Thank you for your help

Comment: you should use php curl